# Jquery validate dependencies between fields array

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation, dependencies, field

I have the following form that I want to validate with the Jquery Validate Plugin:

```
<div class="group">
   <input type="checkbox" name="prod[]" value="1">
   <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1">
</div>
<div class="group">
   <input type="checkbox" name="prod[]" value="2">
   <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1">
</div>
<div class="group">
   <input type="checkbox" name="prod[]" value="3">
   <input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="1">
</div>
```

..etc

**My problem is that the quantity field must be required olny when the relative checkbox is checked.**
For the validation I wrote the following code (but it doesn't work)

```
rules: {
   "prod[]": { //ok it works!
      required: true,
      minlength: 1
   },
   "quant[]": { //not works
      required: {
         depends: function(element) {
            var v = $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');
            return v;
         }
   }
},...
```

How can I do this?
thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you've just made one minor mistake.  The context of the depends call is not the element in question, it's something else.  Therefore, you can't reference `this` in your depends function, instead reference `element`:

```
$(element).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');
```

That's it, will work after that.  You also don't need to make it a depends function I don't think, the required option can be a function as well:

```
required: function(element){
   return $(element).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');
}
```

Comment: Now the last problem is that the error label is always appended to the first element of the fields array. Infact, for example, if there is an error of compilation in the last group, the notify is showed in the first group..Why?

Comment: Validate goes by the `name` attribute for each input, so although you are grouping them by one thing, logically, all the `prod[]` elements are the same "group".  Anyways, to solve your problem, you'll want to add an `errorPlacement` option to validate and then place the error label yourself in there.